# How can I check the code in the exception block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3, rspec-sidekiq

I have Sidekiq worker.

```
class DeliverSmsMessageWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(sms_message_id)
    ....
  rescue StandardError => e
    Rails.logger.error("SmsMessageWorker ERROR: #{e}")
    Bugsnag.notify(e)
  end
end
```

And i write spec, but i get error when i try test `Rails.looger`.

```
describe DeliverSmsMessageWorker, type: :worker do
  subject(:worker) { DeliverSmsMessageWorker }

  context 'on exceptions' do
    let(:error) { StandardError.new('test exception') }

    before do
      allow(worker).to receive(:perform_async).with(sms_message.id).and_raise(error)
    end

    it 'message in logger' do

      Sidekiq::Testing.inline! do
        worker.perform_async(sms_message.id)
        expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:error).and_call_original
      end
    end
  end
end
```

After when i run this specs, I get the error. but why?

Is there any point in testing these two lines?

```
1) DeliverSmsMessageWorker on exceptions message in the logger
 Failure/Error: worker.perform_async(sms_message.id)

 StandardError:
   test exception
```

Comment: Try to move `expect(Rails.logger).to...` to the first line, before `worker.perform_async...`

Comment: as I said in your previous question - mocked expectations have to go before you call the method you are testing.

Comment: I did it, but nothing.

Comment: And if you replace `allow(worker)...` with `expect(worker)...` ?

Comment: but I no need this check, I need to check `Rails.logger` I want to know if it will send a message to the logs or not.   :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use the block syntax for `raise_error` here:

```
  Sidekiq::Testing.inline! do
    expect { worker.perform_async(sms_message.id) }.to raise_error { |error|
      expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:error).and_call_original
    }
  end
```